# MongoDB javascript for maintaining Indices

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to know how to write a Javascript *.js script which can be run on the linux command line via mongo that will re-create indices in a given DB/collection if that DB/collection ever happen to get dropped.  We have a problem wherein whenever we re-create or restore a Mongo DB, the new DB's collections have none of the previously configured indices and we need a script to re-create them.  I've been manually typing one of these commands for each desired index, but I need a way to do it via a script that can be run on the command line whenever we need to re-create the indices.

```
>> use MyDB
>> db.MyCollection1.ensureIndex({
                        "Thing1" : 1,
                        "Thing2" : -1
                })
>> db.MyCollection2.ensureIndex({
                        "Thing3" : 1,
                        "Thing4" : -1
                })
```

How could this be converted into a .js script that can be run all at once?

Comment: just use the mongo shell. it can be used for batch execution.

Comment: I needs to be non interactive.  Something that can be run with a single command like "mongo localhost:27017/MyDB createindex.js"

Comment: that's just what I said - have you even tried it?

Comment: You can use the mongo shell to run some javascript to do this - but I'm more curious to understand how this is happening. How do you dump/restore databases? Indices should get recreated automatically with all standard methods of doing backup/restore. What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: mongodb-org-2.6.5-1.x86_64 is the RPM Im using on CentOS 6.5. Using mongodump/mongorestore seems to leave us with NO indices after a restore as confirmed by db.MyCollection.getIndexes().

My question is how to format the .js so multiple db.MyCollection.ensureIndex() statements can be run one with one mongo command.

Comment: how is it currently formatted?

Answer (score 0):

Create a .js file and use a variable `mydb` to get `db.getSisterDB("MyDB")`. Then you will be able to create indexes for collection in MyDB using `mydb.MyCollection1.ensureIndex`. Run .js file in mongo shell by command: `mongo localhost:27017 filename.js`

```
var mydb = db.getSisterDB("MyDB");
mydb.MyCollection1.ensureIndex({
                        "Thing1" : 1,
                        "Thing2" : -1
                });
mydb.MyCollection2.ensureIndex({
                        "Thing3" : 1,
                        "Thing4" : -1
                });
```

Comment: For some reason this method only creates the first index `Thing1_1_Thing2_-1` not the second index

Comment: Nevermind previous comment. Needed terminal to keep running for the next `createIndex` command to proceed